# Create .tar.gz from a directory omitting some subdirectories and add only new or changed files

Tags: shell-script, backup, tar

I need to create a script, maybe `bash`, maybe just a `.sh` that checks for files changes on a root directory and sub-directories of the root, and adds to a new file. The tar.gz file name should have the creation date at the end (e.g. `monitor-17.06.2013.tar.gz`). I made this:

```
tar -zcvf /home/monitor.tar.gz /var/www/html/monitor --exclude /var/www/html/monitor/cache /var/www/html/monitor/log
```

and it works, but the directory `/var/www/html/monitor/log` isn't omitted, the file name doesn't contain the date, and this is missing the part that adds only new or changed files because I don't know how to do it.

**EDIT: clarify a bit my needs**
Ok, due to some comments by users here I'll try to leave exactly what I'm looking for.

```
Day1: 2013-06-15
Directory: /var/www/html/monitor
Backup File Created: monitor-2013-06-15.tar.gz (contains all the content of /monitor folder)

Day2: 2013-06-16
Directory: /var/www/html/monitor
Files Changed: 
  /var/www/html/monitor/file1.php
  /var/www/html/monitor/log/file2.php
  /var/www/html/monitor/web/file3.php

Files Added: 
  /var/www/html/monitor/index.php
Backup File Created: monitor-2013-06-16.tar.gz (contains **only** the files index.php, file1.php, file2.php and file3.php)

Day3: 2013-06-17
Directory: /var/www/html/monitor
Files Changed: 
  /var/www/html/monitor/index.php
Backup File Created: monitor-2013-06-17.tar.gz (contains **only** the file index.php)
```

The first backup always will have all the content but the rest should only have the modified files and the newest files, nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

To insert the current date in the file name, call the `date` command in a [command substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_substitution).

```
tar -czf monitor-$(date -d %Y-%m-%d).tar.gz …
```

I recommend using a year-month-day format for the date for several reasons: the lexicographic order matches the chronological order; there's no risk of confusion between US month-day-year and rest-of-the-world day-month-year; it's an ISO standard.

To exclude several directories, you need to repeat `--exclude` for each of them: if you write `tar -czf monitor.tar.gz --exclude dir1 dir2`, then `dir2` is a path to include in the archive, only `dir1` is an argument to `--exclude`.

```
tar -czf monitor-$(date -d %Y-%m-%d).tar.gz --exclude /var/www/html/monitor/cache /var/www/html/monitor/log /var/www/html/monitor
```

To store files that have been modified after a certain date, pass the `--newer` option. You can specify either a reference file or a date. It is a lot more reliable to work with a timestamp file: create that file before each backup, and use the timestamp file from the previous backup as a reference for the next one.

```
touch monitor-backup.timestamp.new
tar … --newer=./monitor-backup.timestamp
mv -f monitor-backup.timestamp.new monitor-backup.timestamp
```

You seem to be rolling your own incremental backup system. This is surprisingly difficult to do reliably. I recommend using an existing backup application such as [Duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/).

Comment: +1 for mentioning Duplicity. Much easier then rolling your own!

Comment: @Guilles I'm not trying to get my own incremental backup system I just want a new tar.gz file each time but only with files changed or added from a start point. See my edition at main post

Comment: @Reynier What you are doing is an incremental backup (at the granularity of files). The tar options I gave you do everything you ask, but I recommend using a dedicated tool nonetheless.

Comment: @Gilles let me see if I understood the process: **1** Create the first file by using `tar -czvf monitor-$(date -d %Y-%m-%d).tar.gz --exclude /var/www/html/monitor/cache --exclude /var/www/html/monitor/log`, **2** Create the timestamp file by using `touch monitor-backup.timestamp.new`, **3** Create the rest of files by using `tar -czvf monitor-$(date -d %Y-%m-%d).tar.gz --exclude /var/www/html/monitor/cache --exclude /var/www/html/monitor/log --newer=./monitor-backup.timestamp`, **4** Move the files by using `mv -f monitor-backup.timestamp.new monitor-backup.timestamp` is that right?

Answer (score 0):

As for the ommitted directory, you will have to use the `--exclude` option for each directory, it doesn't mean that it excludes everything after it.  Some commands will take comma separated values, but not all of them.

```
tar -zcvf /home/monitor.tar.gz /var/www/html/monitor --exclude /var/www/html/monitor/cache --exclude /var/www/html/monitor/log
```

As for the part of appending the date, with your explanation of what you're looking for, I'm thinking that you can use:

```
-d, --diff, --compare
      find differences between archive and file system
```

edit: Here is a quick little script to do this.  There is no error checking or anything, but it's a start.

```
NEW_FILE="monitor.`date +%d.%m.%Y`.tar.gz"
PREV_FILE={However you want to find this}

tar cf $NEW_FILE `tar --diff -f $PREV_FILE  | awk --field-separator=: '{print $1}' | uniq`
```

Comment: see my edition and for the `--update` I want to create some kind of difference to reduce the file size. Less said for example first file will have 20MB but second will have only 20kb because only two files was edited, this is what I want

Comment: I added a part about using `--diff` which may be useful to you here.